# how do i map <c-j> without a delay

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I dont care what `<c-j>` does (I think new line or something?)

I've been using `kj` very quickly to enter normal mode instead of `<esc>` but im finding this irritating every time i type a k or j it jumbles them up. It never affects the code because as soon as i type past it they fix instantly but im still getting tired of seeing that.

Not to mention i think control+j would be even faster.

The problem is it causes a slight delay before it enters normal mode, because the combo is used elsewehre. how can i explicitly overwrite any other mappings?

Comment: You know ctrl-c escapes from insert to normal too, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the contending mappings:

```
:imap <C-j>
```

Drop the ones you didn't want:

```
:iunmap <NL>a
:iunmap <NL>b
:iunmap <NL>c
```

(note that `<NL>` is indeed an effective synonym for `<C-j>`)

Comment: how do i put this in my vimrc? it just says mapping not found and i put just the ones i see? I see `<NL>d`

Comment: This is what I have in .vimrc:
`iunmap <NL>d

inoremap <c-j> <Esc>  `

Comment: You may find out where `<NL>d` is mapped by doing `:verbose imap <NL>d`. It could be that it gets mapped _after_ you tried to unmap it from $MYVIMRC (e.g. by a filetype plugin)

Comment: @Tallboy General solution: see `:h after-directory` or `:h :autocmd`+`:h VimEnter`+`:h FileType`. Better is to read help for plugins that are mapping unneeded sequences (what plugins do this you can see by using `verbose imap <C-j>`), there may be other ways for fixing it. Note that @sehe is not quit true in the above comment: *any* plugin is sourced *after* vimrc, not just filetype, see `:h initialization`.

Comment: @ZyX for the record, I didn't say anything would be loaded before vimrc. I said "I could be it **gets mapped** after..." - which is the only relevant bit, really. Thanks for the other additions. I doubt whether reading all about Vim's init/plugin model and itegration mechanisms is really necessary to sustain a user-defined mapping. It'll be enough to understand that plugins (re)define mappings. IMO.

Comment: @sehe You have a rather strange example: “(e.g. by a filetype plugin)” while knowing about the fact that *any* plugin is loaded after vimrc I would say at least “(e.g. by a plugin)” (likely even without “e.g.”). It is strange because it is nine characters more for no reason and being so specific in an example *may* mean you don’t know that other plugins are loaded after vimrc as well.